# Grouping cities by first letters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have table on mysql like this:

```
insert  into `city` (`ID`,`NAMES`) values 
(1,'Białystok, Radom, Sandomierz'),
(2,'Olsztyn, Warka, Grójec, Poznań'),
(3,'Białowieża, Zakopane, Wrocław, Gdańsk, Sopot'),
(4,'Augustów, Kielce')
```

After select I would like to see a view, like:
A B C D.........Z - links to section
A
  Augustów
B
  Białystok
  Białowieża
G
Gdańsk
Grójec
How do this in PHP?

Comment: use `ORDER BY` in query

Comment: You might need to look into this too: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: You might want to use `<optgroup>` tag.

Comment: This database design doesn't feel right at all. Why are you storing (seemingly) random numbers of city names in a single column?

Comment: Are you storing CSV (Comma Separated Values) within a MySQL table.. You should learn about normalization..

Comment: Read up on database normalisation in order to make your data easier to work with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with this PHP code. 
You may help this.

```
$arr = array("Sky","Stackoverflow","Cloud", "Birds","Banana", "Rainbow", "Moon","Apple","Aeroplane","Ambulance");
sort($arr);

$last = '';
$concate = "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    $first = substr($val,0,1);
    if($first == $last)
    {
        $concate .= '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }
    else
    {
        $concate .= $first;
        $concate .= '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }   
    $last = $first; 
}
$concate .= "</ul>";
echo $concate;
```